# Apple keyboard without forced incline, full-size layout, with flat keys, and thin

Tags: keyboards

I am looking for a keyboard with the following properties:

- no forced incline
- full-size layout (i.e. not compact layout)
- flat keys
- Apple QWERTY layout (i.e., standard layout of official Apple keyboards sold in the United States), or something close to it.
- thin
- wired or wireless is fine (slight preference toward wireless though)

Ideally, it should be:

- below 100 USD
- available in the United States

---

To be clear on the terms:

Example of keyboard with forced incline: [MB110LL/B](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005DPF08E)

[image]

Example of keyboard with flat key: [MYLE® Ultra Thin Wired USB Mini Keyboard for Mac and PC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UY9F8HW)

[image]

Example of keyboard with compact layout:  [GMYLE® Ultra Thin Wired USB Mini Keyboard for Mac and PC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003PHJJV6)

[image]

Example of thin keyboard: [Logitech Illuminated Keyboard K740](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001F51G16):

[image]

More generally, a keyboard similar to the Logitech Illuminated Keyboard K740 but with Apple layout would be perfect.

Comment: By Apple, do you mean manufactured by Apple or compatible with Apple?

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend the **[Logitech K750 Solar](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-solar-keyboard-k750-mac)**.

[image]

I've had this keyboard for over a year and it's perfect. I have zero complaints.

I'm very familiar with Apple's keyboards so the shift to this keyboard has been effortless. It's thin, and has flat keys. The layout is also designed for mass with the function keys having their appropriate icons.

---

Specs:

- Solar Powered (I've had this almost year and it's still 100%)
- Flat keys
- Thin design
- Full-size keyboard
- Apple Layout / Design

The price is **$59.99** USD, though you may be able to find it cheaper.

---

Thin:

[image]

Available colors:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's not too annoying to have alt and option on the same key?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt on Mac, `alt` is called `option`, both are usually listed on the key consistency I believe. All the keys are the same except for `fn` which is off too this side but to me this isn't such a big problem

Answer (score 0):

## Apple Keyboard with Numeric Keypad

Apple sells nearly what you want in the [Apple Keyboard with Numeric Keypad](https://www.apple.com/us/search/Apple-Keyboard-with-Numeric-Keypad-US-English?rdt=redirectionFromProductPage&tab=accessories). Costs $ 50 USD.

Just attach some rubber bumpers under the front corners to eliminate the incline.

[image]
<sub>(source: [cdn-apple.com](https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4194/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/M/B1/MB110LL/MB110LL?wid=400&hei=400&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1400774915255))</sub>